# Why a module's singleton method is not visible in downstream eigenclasses where it gets mixed?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins, eigenclass

I understand the regular method lookup path i.e. `class, superclass/module, all the way up to BasicObject`. I thought it was true for singleton version of the chain also but doesn't seem the case when you mixin a module in the meta-chain. I'd appreciate if someone can explain why in the following example `Automobile` module's `banner` method is called instead of its singleton version when I have included this module in Vehicle's eigenclass.

```
module Automobile
  def banner
    "I am a regular method of Automobile"
  end

  class << self
    def banner
      "I am a class method of Automobile"
    end
  end
end

class Vehicle 
  def banner
    "I am an instance method of Vehicle"
  end

  class << self
    include Automobile
    def banner
      puts "I am a class method of Vehicle"
      super
    end
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def banner
    "I am an instance method of Car"
  end

  class << self
    def banner
      puts "I am a class method of Car"
      super
    end
  end
end

puts Car.banner

# I am a class method of Car
# I am a class method of Vehicle
# I am a regular method of Automobile
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, `include` does not include eigenclass methods as you might expect. Consider:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def do_something
      puts "Foo's eigenclass method does something"
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.do_something
# undefined method `do_something' for Bar:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Note that this is consistent with the behavior of classically defined class methods:

```
module Foo
  def self.do_something
    puts "Foo's class method does something"
  end
end

module Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.do_something
# undefined method `do_something' for Bar:Module (NoMethodError)
```

A common idiom is to define the class methods in a submodule and then trigger a call to `extend` when the module is included:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def do_something
      puts "Foo::ClassMethod's instance method does something"
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.do_something
# Foo::ClassMethod's instance method does something
```

The second thing to note is, that you are really including the instance methods of `Automobile` into the eigenclass of `Vehicle`, thus the instance methods of `Automobile` turn into (eigen)class methods of `Vehicle`.

Your `Car` class basically has nothing to do with all this. The only thing to note here is, that class inheritance also makes class methods available, whereas `include` does not. Example:

```
class Foo
  def self.do_something
    puts "Foo's class method does something"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

puts Bar.do_something
# "Foo's class method does something"
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your response. I get it that when I include a module its eigenclass methods are ignored and only its instance methods are exposed to the class. What I am actually trying to understand is the rationale behind this behaviour?

Comment: It's simply consistent behavior. But i honestly don't know why you can't `include` class methods.

Comment: maybe we're looking at it from different vantage points but when you extend a class its instance as well as eigenclass methods are exposed to child class (Car in this example has access to both `Vehicle.banner` as well as `Vehicle.new.banner`). And thus withholding Automobile's singleton `banner` method from Vehicle seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Yes, but inheritance is not the same! `include` by definition only includes instance methods. Class inheritance does both. Remember, that modules are nothing more than a mechanism to group other code together.

Comment: Searching through archives I found in Matz words - `Mix-in is used for several purposes and some of them can be hindered
by inheriting class methods, for example, I don't want to spill
internal methods when including the Math module.  I am not against for some kind of inclusion that inherits class methods as well, but it should be separated from the current #include behavior.`

Comment: Got it: `Class` is a `Module` and `Class` does more stuff than `Module`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a class is an object, just like the other objects it also has its own superclass;
second of all, Eigenclass itself is a normal class, only anonymous and sorta invisible;
third, the eigenclass's superclass of the derived class is the eigenclass of the base class;
Fourth, `include` includes instance methods (not singleton methods) of the included module, make them instance methods of the receiver class object.

There're two parallel inheritance chains in your example

Car < Vehicle < ...

Car's eigenclass < Vehicle's eigenclass < Automobile < ...

Do the following test on irb:

```
class Object
  def eigenclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

Car.ancestors # => [Car, Vehicle, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Car.eigenclass.ancestors # => [Automobile, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Vehicle.eigenclass.ancestors # => [Automobile, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Car.eigenclass.superclass.equal? Vehicle.eigenclass # => true
```

You see, `Automobile` is in the eigenclass inheritance chain. But regretably, the `ancestor` method doesn't return invisible eigenclasses, nonetheless they are actually in the second chain.

Comment: I like your `eigenclass` definition on `Object`. And you should change `ancestor` to `ancestors`.

Comment: It is helpful for inspection to add an eigenclass method to Object like above. Surprised this has not found its way into Ruby by default