# Class, Module, their eigenclasses, and method lookup

Tags: ruby, class, module, lookup, eigenclass

Let's open class `Module` and add a method to it:

```
class Module  
  def foo  
    puts "phew"  
  end  
end
```

I can call this method by doing this,

```
Class.foo
```

which is understandable because class of `Class` is `Class`, whose superclass is `Module`. so it can call instance methods defined in `Module`.

[image: relation between classes and modules]

Now, the method `bar` below is defined on `Module`'s eigenclass:

```
class Module  
   def self.bar  
     puts "bar"  
   end  
end
```

but now

```
Class.bar
```

also works.

Can someone explain me how `Class` can access methods in `Module`'s eigenclass?

---

I think I got it now. Method look up doesn't work the way I explained before. when I do `Class.foo`, the method is searched in `Class`'s eigenclass and then it's superclass which is `Module`'s eigenclass all the way upto `BasicObject`'s eigenclass at which point it turns upon itself (like a serpent eating it's own tail) to look for method in `Class` (as `Class` is the superclass of `BasicObject`'s eigenclass) and then to it's superclass `Module`, where it finds the method.

Similarly, when I do `Class.bar`, method is searched in `Class`'s eigenclass and then in `Module`'s eigenclass where it finds it.

When I do

```
class Class   
  def check  
    puts "class instance method"  
  end
end
```

and

```
class Module   
  def self.check    
    puts "modules eigenclass method"     
  end    
  def check    
    puts "module instance method"   
  end     
end
```

guess wot is the output when I do:

```
Class.check
```

This is my current understanding:
[image: current understanding]

Comment: Related discussion I found helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269271/why-a-modules-singleton-method-is-not-visible-in-downstream-eigenclasses-where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote a pretty [extensive tutorial](https://github.com/kyrylo/entooru/blob/master/articles/20130322_understanding_method_lookup_in_ruby_20/en/en_understanding_method_lookup_in_ruby_20.md), including new Ruby 2.0 behavior.

Note: the term used in Ruby is `singleton_class`, not `eigenclass`.

Comment: Link at that url is dead

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly comprehensive overview of Ruby's method lookup behaviour when Eigenclasses are involved in [this blog post by Andrea Singh](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html). Notably, the "Eigenclasses and Class Inheritance" section near the very end contains a useful lookup diagram that should address your questions.

Comment: Is this current as of Ruby 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a tutorial about the `eigenclass` in Ruby:

[Understanding the eigenclass in less than 5 minutes](https://medium.com/rubycademy/understanding-the-eigenclass-in-less-than-5-minutes-dcb8ca223eb4)