# Why am I able to use Kernel singleton methods like `puts`?

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

In Ruby, the method `puts` is a singleton method of the `Kernel` module.

Normally, when a module is `include`d or `extend`ed by another module, the module (but not its singleton class) is added to the inheritance tree. That effectively makes the *instance* methods of the module available to either the module or its singleton class (for `include` and `extend`, respectively)... but the *singleton* methods of a mixed-in module remain inaccessible, because the singleton class of a module isn't ever added to the inheritance tree.

So why can I use `puts` (and other Kernel singleton methods)?

```rb
Kernel.singleton_methods(false)

# => [:caller_locations, :local_variables, :require, :require_relative, :autoload, :sprintf, :format, :Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :test, :warn, :autoload?, :fork, :binding, :exit, :raise, :fail, :global_variables, :__method__, :__callee__, :__dir__, :URI, :eval, :iterator?, :block_given?, :catch, :throw, :loop, :gets, :sleep, :proc, :lambda, :trace_var, :untrace_var, :at_exit, :load, :Rational, :select, :Complex, :syscall, :open, :printf, :print, :putc, :puts, :readline, :readlines, :`, :p, :system, :spawn, :exec, :exit!, :abort, :set_trace_func, :rand, :srand, :trap, :caller]
```

Note that `puts` *does not* seem to be an instance method on `Kernel`:

```rb
Kernel.instance_methods.grep(/puts/)

# []
```

Although `Object` does include `Kernel`

```rb
Object.included_modules

# [Kernel]
```

as far as I can tell, `Kernel`'s singleton class (`#<Class:Kernel>`) doesn't show up in the ancestors of any object. `is_a?` appears to agree with this:

```rb
Object.is_a? Class.singleton_class # false
Object.is_a? Kernel.singleton_class # false

Object.singleton_class.is_a? Class.singleton_class # true
Object.singleton_class.is_a? Kernel.singleton_class # false
```

Yet, for some reason, they show up as private methods for every object.

```rb
Object.puts "asdf"

# NoMethodError (private method `puts' called for Object:Class)
```

How does the method lookup find these methods at all if `#<Class:Kernel>` doesn't show up in the ancestor chain?

Related:

- [Ruby method lookup path for an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848667/ruby-method-lookup-path-for-an-object)
- [Class, Module, their eigenclasses, and method lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475658/class-module-their-eigenclasses-and-method-lookup)

  - Note: this is different from what I'm asking, because this is class inheritance, so `#<Class:Class>` inherits from `#<Class:Module>`
- [Why a module's singleton method is not visible in downstream eigenclasses where it gets mixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269271/why-a-modules-singleton-method-is-not-visible-in-downstream-eigenclasses-where)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place.

Methods like [`Kernel#Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array), [`Kernel#Complex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex), [`Kernel#Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Float), [`Kernel#Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash), [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), [`Kernel#Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Rational), [`Kernel#String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-String), [`Kernel#__callee__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__), [`Kernel#__dir__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__), [`Kernel#__method__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__), [`` Kernel#` ``](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60), [`Kernel#abort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-abort), [`Kernel#at_exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit), [`Kernel#autoload`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload), [`Kernel#autoload?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload-3F), [`Kernel#binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-binding), [`Kernel#block_given?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F), [`Kernel#callcc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-callcc), [`Kernel#caller`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller), [`Kernel#caller_locations`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations), [`Kernel#catch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-catch), [`Kernel#eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), [`Kernel#exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec), [`Kernel#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit), [`Kernel#exit!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21), [`Kernel#fail`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-fail), [`Kernel#fork`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-fork), [`Kernel#format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-format), [`Kernel#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), [`Kernel#global_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-global_variables), [`Kernel#initialize_clone`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-initialize_clone), [`Kernel#initialize_copy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-initialize_copy), [`Kernel#initialize_dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-initialize_dup), [`Kernel#iterator?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-iterator-3F), [`Kernel#lambda`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda), [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load), [`Kernel#local_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables), [`Kernel#loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), [`Kernel#open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-open), [`Kernel#p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p), [`Kernel#pp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-pp), [`Kernel#print`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print), [`Kernel#printf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-printf), [`Kernel#proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-proc), [`Kernel#putc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-putc), [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), [`Kernel#raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise), [`Kernel#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-rand), [`Kernel#readline`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-readline), [`Kernel#readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-readlines), [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require), [`Kernel#require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), [`Kernel#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-select), [`Kernel#set_trace_func`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func), [`Kernel#sleep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep), [`Kernel#spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), [`Kernel#srand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-srand), [`Kernel#syscall`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-syscall), [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system), [`Kernel#test`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-test), [`Kernel#throw`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-throw), [`Kernel#trace_var`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-trace_var), [`Kernel#trap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-trap), [`Kernel#untrace_var`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-untrace_var), and [`Kernel#warn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-warn) don't do anything useful with their receiver. They don't call private methods, they don't access instance variables, they in fact *completely ignore* what `self` is.

Therefore, it would be misleading if you call them like this:

```
foo.puts 'Hello, World!'
```

Because a reader would be mislead into thinking that `puts` does something with `foo`, when in fact, it completely ignores it. (This applies *especially* to the printing family of methods, because there also exist [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) and friends, which indeed *do* care about their receiver.)

So, in order to prevent you from misleadingly calling these methods with a receiver, they are made `private`, which means they can only be called without an explicit receiver. (Obviously, they will *still* be called on `self`, but at least that won't be so obvious visually.)

Technically, these aren't really methods *at all*, they behave more like *procedures*, but Ruby doesn't have procedures, so this is the best way to "fake" them.

The reason why they are *also* defined as *singleton methods* is so that you can still call them in contexts where `Kernel` is not in the inheritance hierarchy, e.g. something like this:

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  def works
    ::Kernel.puts 'Hello, World!'
  end

  def doesnt
    puts 'Hello, World!'
  end
end

f = Foo.new

f.works
# Hello, World!

f.doesnt
# NoMethodError: undefined method `puts' for #<Foo:0x00007f97cf918ed0>
```

And the reason why they need to be defined separately at all is that the instance method versions are `private`. If they *weren't*, then you would simply be able to call `Kernel.puts` anyway, because `Object` includes `Kernel` and `Kernel` is an instance of `Module` which is a subclass of `Object`, thus `Kernel` is an indirect instance of itself. However, the methods *are* `private` and thus you would get a

```
NoMethodError: private method `puts' called for Kernel:Module
```

instead. Therefore, they need to be duplicated separately. There is actually a helper method that does that: [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function). (This is also used for [`Math`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Math.html), where you can either call e.g. `Math.sqrt(4)` or `include Math; sqrt(4)`. In this case, you have the choice of `include`ing `Math` or not, whereas `Kernel` is pre-`include`d in `Object` always.)

So, in summary: the methods are duplicated as `private` *instance* methods of `Kernel` as well as `public` *singleton* methods (which is really just *instance* methods of `Kernel`'s *singleton class*). The reason they are defined as `private` instance methods is so they cannot be called with an explicit receiver and are forced to look more like *procedures*. The reason they are duplicated as singleton methods of `Kernel` is so that they *can* be called with an explicit receiver as long as that explicit receiver is `Kernel`, in contexts where `Kernel` is not available in the inheritance hierarchy.

Check this out:

```
#ruby --disable-gems --disable-did_you_mean -e'puts Kernel.private_instance_methods(false).sort'
Array
Complex
Float
Hash
Integer
Rational
String
__callee__
__dir__
__method__
`
abort
at_exit
autoload
autoload?
binding
block_given?
caller
caller_locations
catch
eval
exec
exit
exit!
fail
fork
format
gets
global_variables
initialize_clone
initialize_copy
initialize_dup
iterator?
lambda
load
local_variables
loop
open
p
pp
print
printf
proc
putc
puts
raise
rand
readline
readlines
require
require_relative
respond_to_missing?
select
set_trace_func
sleep
spawn
sprintf
srand
syscall
system
test
throw
trace_var
trap
untrace_var
warn
```

Answer (score 3):

"How does the method lookup find these methods at all if # doesn't show up in the ancestor chain?"

```
 1.class.included_modules #  => [Comparable, Kernel]
```

Quoting OP:

`Kernel.instance_methods.grep(/puts/)
 # []`

As you have found yourself, private instance methods don't show up, they do with `Kernel.private_instance_methods`.

Comment: Yes, `Object` includes the `Kernel` module, but `puts` et al. are not methods on `Kernel` -- they are methods on `Kernel`'s singleton class, and thus should not be accessible to `Object`

Comment: Try this: `module M; def self.m; end end` `Object.include M` `Object.included_modules # => [M, Kernel]` `Object.m # NoMethodError (undefined method 'm' for Object:Class)`

Comment: I think `Kernel` works like this: `module M;
 private;
 def m;
 end;
end;
Object.include M`

Comment: aha.... it turns out that `#instance_methods` does not include private methods. I didn't realize that. `Kernel.private_instance_methods` does indeed include `#puts` and others. If you update your answer to explain that, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the answer is that I was asking the wrong question. **Why am I able use Kernel singleton methods like `puts`?** The answer is: **you can't**.

`Kernel`'s singleton methods, like all other singleton methods on modules, are not inheritable. The trick is that they aren't singleton methods, *per se*... they're **module functions**.

Creating a module function in ruby *creates two copies of the method*: **a singleton method** and a **private instance method**. That's why `Kernel.singleton_method(:puts)` and `Kernel.instance_method(:puts)` both work.

So, because `Object` `include`s `Kernel`, it gets access to its instance methods, including `puts`.

I made a mistake by using `#instance_methods`, which only shows public instance methods. To see private ones, I need to use `#private_instance_methods`, e.g.:

```rb
Kernel.private_instance_methods(false).grep(/puts/)

# [:puts]
```